# Error when timer is elapsed and trying to show new Window C#

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, show

I have a timer in my simple app :

```
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 3000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

which is calling this function each time is elapsed

```
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        DisplayWindow displayedWindow = new DisplayWindow();
        displayedWindow.Show();
        ...
    }
```

and `displayedWindow` is a `WPF` form which have just the created code itself (and my close button):

```
public partial class DisplayWindow : Window
{
    public DisplayWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

and when I run my app there is an error in place

```
public DisplayWindow()
```

which have message like this:

```
 "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this".
```

I was trying to read some threads and what I have just found is to play with STA Thread which I did, however without success.
How may I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a System.Timers.Timer is used in a WPF application, it is worth noting that the System.Timers.Timer runs on a different thread then the user interface (UI) thread. In order to access objects on the user interface (UI) thread, it is necessary to post the operation onto the Dispatcher of the user interface (UI) thread using Invoke or BeginInvoke. Reasons for using a DispatcherTimer opposed to a System.Timers.Timer are that the DispatcherTimer runs on the same thread as the Dispatcher and a DispatcherPriority can be set on the DispatcherTimer.

Consider using a [`DispatcherTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) for this :

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Tick += OnTimedEvent;
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
timer.Start();
```

And, change your handler signature to :

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the timer event require the UI to invoke your method, without invoking it on the spot. The UI thread will **later** invoke your method as soon as possible.

This is an example taken from MSDN. I leave it to you to adapt your timer handler accordingly:

```
if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
{   
    SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
    this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
}
else
{
    this.textBox1.Text = text;
}
```